# Column space of a product of unitary matrix and orthogonal projector

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I want to show that $\operatorname{col}(\boldsymbol U^*\boldsymbol P_M \boldsymbol U) = \operatorname{col}(\boldsymbol U^*\boldsymbol M)$, where $\boldsymbol P_M$ is the orthogonal projector onto $\operatorname{col}(\boldsymbol M)$ and $\boldsymbol U$ is unitary. How can I do this? I thought about using the fact that $\operatorname{col}(\boldsymbol P_M\boldsymbol U)$ is a subspace of $\operatorname{col}(\boldsymbol P_M) = \operatorname{col}(\boldsymbol M)$, but I need equalities rather than subsets.

Comment: That's a very good idea to start. It turns out that $\operatorname{col}(P_MU)=\operatorname{col}(P_M)=\operatorname{col}(M)$. Can you prove this? (Hint: you can use a property of unitary matrices $U$)

Comment: I will try and show that, thank you. I initially tried writing $\boldsymbol P_M\boldsymbol x = \boldsymbol y$ so that $\boldsymbol y \in \operatorname{col}(\boldsymbol P_M)$, and then trying to deriving $\boldsymbol P_M\boldsymbol U\boldsymbol \xi = \boldsymbol y$ for some other $\boldsymbol \xi$ but got stuck there. I'm sure I'm just overlooking something simple here with $\boldsymbol U$.

Comment: That's right. Now, recall what the meaning of unitary is for $U$, that is what you need to make the final step.

Comment: Ah, if I just write $\boldsymbol x$ as $\boldsymbol U(\boldsymbol U^*\boldsymbol x)$, using $\boldsymbol U\boldsymbol U^* = \boldsymbol I$, I can let $\boldsymbol \xi = \boldsymbol U^*\boldsymbol x$ and write $\boldsymbol P_M\boldsymbol U\boldsymbol \xi = \boldsymbol y$ so that $\boldsymbol y \in \operatorname{col}(\boldsymbol P_M\boldsymbol U)$, giving $\operatorname{col}(\boldsymbol P_M\boldsymbol U) \subseteq \operatorname{col}(\boldsymbol P_M) \subseteq \operatorname{col}(\boldsymbol P_MU)$ and hence equality. How's that?

Comment: That's what I had in mind, yes.